# SQLAlchemy cast boolean column to int

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table of user records and I wish to see the average when some condition is met. the condition column is a boolean.
In Postgresql I could cast it easily:

```
select id, avg(cond::INT) from table group by id;
```

But in SQLAlchemy I couldn't find anything equivalent to `::INT`.
How do i deal with the type conversion?
I have

```
orm_query(Table.id, func.avg(Table.cond))
```

which, of course, returns an error.

Comment: from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast OR from sqlalchemy import cast Have you tried?  cast(Table.cond, sqlalchemy.Integer)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `<expr>::<type>` is [Postgresql specific syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS), `CAST(<expr> AS <type>)` the standard SQL equivalent. In SQLAlchemy you can produce a type cast expression with a variety of ways. In this case you can simply:

```
orm_query(Table.id, func.avg(Table.cond.cast(Integer)))
```

Another option is to use the [`cast()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) construct.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `cast` fuction to convert boolean to integer:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast
import sqlalchemy

orm_query(Table.id, func.avg(cast(Table.cond, sqlalchemy.Integer)))
```